# Can interpol detain me in the USA, Europe or Canada for dodging draft in countries like Russia, Belarus?

Tags: international-travel, russia, regulations, officials, belarus

Can interpol detain citizens of CIS-countries(Russia, Belarus, Kazakhstan, Tajikistan, Armenia) in the USA, Europe or Canada for dodging draft in home countries?

Comment: Do you mean during a short stay (visit visa), or as an expat/immigrant/asylum seeker? It may be pretty difficult to get admitted as a visitor is such a situation, or even more difficult to leave your home country in the first place. Additionally, if you overstay your visit visa and get deported, you're in trouble again.

Comment: Highly unlikely. You should be in nationwide wanted list first (федеральный розыск if it is Russia), which is a complex procedure itself for draft dodgers and rarely done. I have no proofs as Interpol doesn't publish Red Notice statistics but I strongly believe you have little to zero chances to be busted for such type of crime.

Comment: Were you convicted of draft dodging? Was there any kind of legal procedure started against you? If not and you were simply ignoring them, then Interpol doesn't know about you.

Comment: @sashkello I wanna know, even if I am convicted, will the Canadian/US/EU police detain me, since it's draft dodging is not a crime in Canada/US/most of EU countries

Comment: @HypeTotec If you are convicted, it depends on how badly your country wants you. If you are an average nobody, then they wouldn't bother to issue a nationwide warrant for you, and so wouldn't pass your info to Interpol.

Comment: @sashkello what I was trying to know is whether extradition depends on what is considered a crime and whatis not in the country that received a red notice. For example, if I escaped directly from conscription point, insulted the officer with words "fuck you" but somehow managed to get to Canada or USA legally through third countries, with valid Canadian/American visa etc, and my country put me on a nationwide warrant. Will Canada/USA detain and extradite me, given that neither draft dodging, nor saying "fuck you" are not considered serious crime in Canada/USA?

Comment: @HypeTotec In a foreign country rights which are applicable to the citizens of that country aren't applicable to you. They can do it, there is nothing which prevents them from deporting you (or denying access) for WHATEVER reason. They can literally stop you at the border with a valid visa, talk to you and deny you entry because you look suspicious. There is NO LAW which prevents them from cancelling your visa either. They don't have to convict you - they can't judge on crimes and legality of what you did, regarding your country of origin. That's not their business.

Comment: @sashkello yeah but I consider it rediculous if, for example, Sweden hands to Saudi Arabia someone who was given a red notice for blasphemy, which is punishable by death in Saudi Arabia. Likewise, given that East European countries are corrupt and there is no alternative service, I think it's unlikely that they would WANT to deport me for such nonsensical, from their viewpoint, reasons.

Comment: @HypeTotec Well, that's exactly the point I'm making. They can, there is nothing stopping them. They are highly unlikely to do so. There is no guarantee either way.

Answer (score 3):

Interpol does not detain. It passes a [Red Notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpol_notice#Notice_types) from one member country to the others. Those countries may or may not act on those notices, and then there would be extradition proceedings which vary from country to country.

As of [April 2018](https://www.interpol.int/Member-countries/News/N20180523), EU countries were still extraditing to Russia on some charges, while Interpol refused another Russian notice in [October 2017](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-10-26/interpol-blocks-russia-s-warrant-to-arrest-hermitage-s-browder).